# Windows Phone 8.1 - GeofenceState.Exited

Tags: geolocation, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I want to ask how is GeofenceState.Exited intended?
When I have a background task with GeofenceState.Entered, when I move inside the circle, I get IBackgroundTask.Run() run every 2 minutes (**why 2 minutes?**)

But with GeofenceState.Exited, I can walk miles, but it never gets triggered. Is there some bug, or is that intended differently than I suppose? I guess it should work this way: when the check is done after 2 minutes, when I'm outside of the circle, the method Run is called.

I have a parameter 50 and dwell time 1 sec.

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code. This sounds strange.

Comment: I don't think it is meant to be realtime. Checking the location every two minutes sounds like reasonable behaviour.